# What the difference between using the class reference type Object and the class reference type String when creating a new string?

Tags: java, inheritance, reference, polymorphism, superclass

I have learned that Java string variables are objects and that you can create them by instantiating the `String` class in the `java.lang` package like this:

```
String myString = new String("hello");
```

What is the difference between:

- Creating a string by instantiating the `String` class using the `String` reference type as above
- And creating a `String` by instantiating the `String` class using an `Object` reference type such as:

  ```
  Object myString = new String("hello");
  ```

?

Comment: When you have a variable of type `Object` you can only perform methods of `Object` on it.

Comment: Also, you should never use `new String` here. Just use ``String myString = "hello";``

Answer (score 0):

The object you create is the object you create. How you reference it is separate but related.

In the code below, `string2` and `string3` are both `String` objects, created the same way.

So `string2` is a `String` reference. This allows you to access everything "String-ish" about the object. You can also reference everything "Object-ish" because all `String`s are `Object`s; that is, because `Object` is a superclass (parent) of `String`

But `string3` is an `Object` reference, and "does not know" that the object is a `String`. It only knows it is an `Object`. You can only access "Object-ish" fields and methods, not "String-ish" methods. To access "String-ish" methods, you would need to cast the reference to the true class it is. That is what `string4` is.

---

Additionally, `String` has special behaviour within Java. Possibly you should use a different class to clarify the reference concept. (Experiment with your own class heirarchy.)

You can create a `String` without using the `new` keyword, but instead using `"string constant"` syntax. This creates the `String` in a special place in memory known as "interned". All interned `String`s with identical text are the *exact same object* in memory. They are not just equal, they are identical.

In the code below, `string1` and `string5` are interned `String`s. The others are not.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String string1 = "hello";
    String string2 = new String("hello");
    Object string3 = new String("hello");
    String string4 = (String) string3;
    String string5 = new String("hello").intern();
    
    System.out.println(string1 == string2); // false
    System.out.println(string1 == string5); // true
    System.out.println(string4 == string3); // true
    
    System.out.println(string1.getClass().equals(string2.getClass())); // true
    System.out.println(string1.getClass().equals(string3.getClass())); // true
    System.out.println(string1.getClass().equals(string5.getClass())); // true
    
    
    System.out.println(string1.equals(string2)); // true
    System.out.println(string1.equals(string3)); // true
    System.out.println(string1.equals(string5)); // true
}
```